# Toshiba Satellite L755-S5246 - Does someone have all Fkey commands for this laptop?

Tags: toshiba-laptop

Does someone have all the F-key command for a Toshiba Satellite l755-s5246 laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium?

Answer (score 1):

**Guide for Satellite/Satellite Pro L750D/L740D/L730/L740/L750 Series**

Fn + F10 = This hot key turns the cursor control overlay on and off.

Fn + F11 = This hot key turns the numeric overlay on and off.

Fn + F12 = This hot key turns the scroll lock feature on and off.

Fn + End PRTSC = This hot key takes a snapshot of your display screen

Fn + 1 = This hot key allows you to zoom out.

Fn + 2 = This hot key allows you to zoom in.

Fn + 3 = This hot key decreases the speaker volume.

Fn + 4 = This hot key increases the speaker volume.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHkVJ.png

Manual for the 700 Series can be [found here](https://support.dynabook.com/support/staticContentDetail?contentId=3116945&isFromTOCLink=false)